# MethodNotAllowedHttpException when POST method (Laravel 5.5)

Tags: laravel-5

In my /reoutes/api.php i have the following route

```
Route::middleware('api')->group(function(){

    Route::post('/prepare/', 'CompgenApiController@prepareDefault');

});
```

and when i try open page https://mydomen/api/prepare/ with postman i get an exception "Method Not Allowed Http Exception". Also i added in my VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
protected $except = [
    '/api/prepare/',
];
```

If i replace post on get - all ok!

Comment: So? You need to use a POST-request, not a GET-request.

Comment: api is the middleware. so try to change the `$except` to protected $except = [
    '/prepare/',
];

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the page can only be loaded using a POST request. This error is not to do with CSRF Token verification.

Update Postman to make a POST request to https://mydomen/api/prepare/ instead of GET. Or you can cheat and enable both POST and GET:

```
Route::get('/prepare/', 'CompgenApiController@prepareDefault');
Route::post('/prepare/', 'CompgenApiController@prepareDefault');
```